Force ffmpeg to select libfdk_aac instead of native aac decoder via C API
I have an audio decoding application written using ffmpeg's C api. This decodes compressed audio and converts them to unsigned 32 bit PCM data. I have libfdk_aac linked to ffmpeg, and ffmpeg is compiled from source using the instructions provided in https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos.
However, it appears that even if I specifically request ffmpeg to find and use libfdk_aac, it is switching back to its native aac implementation. For example, as seen the code snippet and its outputs below, the print from variable "codec" shows libfdk_aac with codec ID: 86018 (which comes from AVCodecID enum defined in codec_id.h). The print from the variable "context" shows that it is still using native aac implementation with the codec_id 86018.
const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("libfdk_aac");
fprintf(stderr, "Codec id: %d, name %s , long_name: %s \n", codec->id, codec->name, codec->long_name );
AVCodecContext* context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

int ret = avcodec_open2(context, codec, NULL);
fprintf(stderr, "From context: Codec id: %d, name %s , long_name: %s \n", context->codec_id, context->codec_descriptor->name, context->codec_descriptor->long_name);

The output for the above:
Codec id: 86018, name libfdk_aac , long_name: Fraunhofer FDK AAC 
From context: Codec id: 86018, name aac , long_name: AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) 

When looking at the codec_id.h and its AVCodecID enum, we see that AV_CODEC_ID_AAC corresponds to the ID 86018 and there is no enum defined for libfdk_aac.
    enum AVCodecID
    {
        // ..
        AV_CODEC_ID_AAC, // -> 86018
        AV_CODEC_ID_AC3, // -> 86019
    };

Could you please let me know how to force ffmpeg to use libfdk_aac decoder library instead of its native implementation?
I'm using ffmpeg 5.1 and here is configuration output of it which shows that libfdk_aac and nonfree is enabled. I'm running this on Fedora 40 with Linux kernel 6.10.9-200.fc40.x86_64.
ffmpeg version N-110004-g1231003c3c Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=~/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I~/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L~/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-lm --bindir=~/bin --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --enable-demuxer=spdif --enable-decoder=dolby_e --enable-decoder=ac3 --enable-gpl --enable-decoder=eac3 --enable-indev=alsa --enable-outdev=alsa --enable-libsrt --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl
  libavutil      58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavcodec     60.  6.101 / 60.  6.101
  libavformat    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  4.100 /  9.  4.100
  libswscale      7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

